# Re-order right sidebar under left sidebar with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to achieve the following layouts. Apparently it's not possible flexbox. What is the best way to achieve this effect without javascript?

I have the following elements:

```
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='left-bar'/>
      <div class='center-bar'/>
      <div class='right-bar'/>
    </div>
```

I want the following effect:

Large screen:

`````````
    _____ ________ _____
   |     |        |     |
   | l-b | center | r-b |
    `````|        |     |
          ```````` `````
`````````

medium screen (I CANNOT GET THIS ONE TO WORK):

`````````
    _____ ________ 
   |     |        |
   | l-b | center |
   |`````|        |
   | r-b |```````` 
   |     | 
   ´´´´´´
`````````

small screen:

`````````
    ________ 
   |        |
   |  l-b   |
   |````````|
   |  r-b   | 
   |        | 
   |````````|
   | center | 
   |        | 
    ````````
`````````

At the moment I tried this without success:

```
   .container {
     display: flex;
     flex-flow: row wrap;
   }

   @media (max-width: 960px) {
   .left-bar {
       order: 1;
     }
     .center-bar {
       order: 3;
     }
     .right-bar {
       order: 2;
     }
   }
```

This is what happens, I get a space between the left and the right bar:

`````````
    _____ ________ 
   |     |        |
   | l-b | center |
   |`````|        |
   |`````|```````` 
   | r-b |
   |     | 
   ´´´´´´
`````````